# Box-shadow blur-radius causes left and right shadow

Tags: html, css

Doing a box-shadow on a flex element

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 15px 0px #696868;
```

this is what i have at the moment, and i want it just like this, except that my blur radius causes a slight shadow on the left and right y-offset. How can i make this go away?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxqgv0vz/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `spread-radius` (fourth parameter) to a negative value, to reduce the overall size of the shadow-box, then increase the `offset-y` to make the smaller shadow-box visible. eg.:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 17px 15px -15px #696868;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxqgv0vz/1/)